# Advance integration of ccavenue

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, ccavenue

I have integrated ccavenue payment gateway in my site, on which user redirect to ccavenue.com to fill the form (it can be autofilled) and select the payment option.

But I don't want to redirect users to ccavenue to fill that form and select payment option. Instead I want user can select payment option from my site and redirect directly to that banks interface on behalf on ccavenue.

for example site [mobikwik](http://www.mobikwik.com/) has this type of integration.

Comment: ccavenue give virtual terminal environment go validate credit cards but not give the documentation for that

Answer (score 1):

The integration you are looking for is called 'Seamless Integration'. The documentation for the same can be requested by ccavenue by emailing their technical team and providing your merchant id.

Answer (score 0):

It is called the CCavenue IFRAME integration. You need to contact the ccavenue guys for that. There is a readymade plugin available for IFRAME integration but only for magento. We need to use the php kit provided by the ccavenue and manually integrate it. Its a difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

seamless and PCI/DSS this two term you have search

In ccavenue there is one another method called "iframe checkout form" which seamless you can go with that.

You can have seamless payment integration on your website only if you have PCI-DSS compliance according to the RBI guidelines and security